# Concat multiple columns in notepadd++

Tags: notepad++

I have below 2 columns data , I want to concat them together side by side in notepadd++. Can someone please help how to do this.

**column1**

```
cluster_identifier
cluster_parameter_group
db_parameter_group
instance_class
cluster_instance_count
engine
```

**column2**

```
= "{{ sdf.cluster_identifier }}"
= "{{ sdf.cluster_parameter_group }}"
= "{{ sdf.db_parameter_group }}"
= "{{ sdf.instance_class }}"
= "{{ sdf.cluster_instance_count }}"
= "{{ sdf.engine }}"
= "{{ sdf.engine_version }}"
```

**final version in notepad++**

```
cluster_identifier      = "{{ sdf.cluster_identifier }}"
cluster_parameter_group = "{{ sdf.cluster_parameter_group }}"
db_parameter_group      = "{{ sdf.db_parameter_group }}"
instance_class          = "{{ sdf.instance_class }}"
cluster_instance_count  = "{{ sdf.cluster_instance_count }}"
engine                  = "{{ sdf.engine }}"
engine_version          = "{{ sdf.engine_version }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the second column is build from the first column. Then I'd do something like this:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+$`
- Replace with: `$0\t= "{{ sdf.$0 }}"`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
.+          # 1 or more any character but newline
$           # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$0              # the whole match
\t              # a tabulation
= "{{ sdf.      # literally
$0              # the whole match
 }}"            # literally
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: is there any way I can also take care of indentation of =.* for all the lines one below other

Comment: @AbhishekSolanki: I'm afraid you can't. Try with multiple `\t` instead of 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use columnar cut & paste:

Hold Alt key while using ^C on column2 rows, and then paste them at  the end of row 1 of column1.

[Example](https://superuser.com/questions/1110754/copy-and-paste-in-a-column-in-notepad/1110760)

R

Comment: This also works thanks :) Is there any way I can also take care of indentation of =.* for all the lines one below other

Comment: With my solution, if you add several spaces in first row, before pasting column2,
they will be aligned to the same indentation.

Comment: if I add the spaces in the column2 the indentation becomes unequal . I doesnt give proper all "=" sign properly .

Comment: I didn't tell you to add the spaces to column2,
add the spaces only to first row of column1, and then paste the column one you copied columnarly,
I've just did it, and it works.

If I'm not clear enough, look at 
https://superuser.com/questions/1110754/copy-and-paste-in-a-column-in-notepad/1110760